# Kivy Text Editor Input Not Showing Up

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, kivy

I have unfortuanlly have encourtered an error in kivy and Python 3. I have not found a soultion via Google. I wanted to get text input at the very least but it does not show up. Just the text itself. Thank you for your time!

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class ColdKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        label = Label(text="Cold") #I acutally orginally called it Zone unitil I changed it into Cold cause it's really cold now
        f.add_widget(label)
        txt = TextInput(text='', focus=True, multiline=True, cursor_blink=True, background_color=(1,1,1,1))
        f.add_widget(txt)
        return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ColdKivyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in TextInput when setting the focus in the constructor, a workaround is to set the focus an instant after the window is shown through `Clock`:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

class ColdKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        label = Label(text="Cold") 
        f.add_widget(label)
        txt = TextInput(multiline=True, cursor_blink=True, background_color=(1,1,1,1))
        f.add_widget(txt)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(txt, "focus", True))
        return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ColdKivyApp().run()
```